# fontconfig: cannot change font family

Tags: linux, fonts, fontconfig

this is my ~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">

<fontconfig>

    <match target="font">
        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hinting" mode="assign"><bool>true</bool></edit>
        <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign"><const>hintfull</const></edit>
        <edit name="lcdfilter" mode="assign"><const>lcddefault</const></edit>
        <edit name="rgba" mode="assign"><const>rgb</const></edit>
    </match>

    <alias>
        <family>monospace</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline</family>
            <family>Inconsolata</family>
            <family>Menlo</family>
            <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>

    <alias>
        <family>sans-serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>DejaVu Sans</family>
            <family>Droid Sans</family>
            <family>Ubuntu</family>
            <family>Helvetica</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>

    <alias>
        <family>serif</family>
        <prefer>
            <family>DejaVu Serif</family>
            <family>Bitstream Vera Serif</family>
            <family>Times New Roman</family>
        </prefer>
    </alias>

</fontconfig>
```

as you can see, I want Meslo as my preferred monospace font. I got the name from `fc-list | grep Meslo`:

```
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG M DZ Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG L DZ Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG L DZ for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG L Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG L for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG S DZ Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG S DZ for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG M Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG M for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG S Regular for Powerline.otf: Meslo LG S for Powerline:style=RegularForPowerline
```

Config file is enabled in /etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf:

```
<include ignore_missing="yes" prefix="xdg">fontconfig/fonts.conf</include>
```

**I ran `fc-cache -vf` and rebooted, then tried `fc-match monospace` and was expecting Meslo, but got Inconsolata instead. Why?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently I had a typo in my family-name, I did `fc-list | grep Meslo` and copy pasted the bold part into the `<family>` tag:

/usr/share/fonts/OTF/Meslo LG M DZ Regular for Powerline.otf: **Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline**:style=RegularForPowerline

my config now looks like:

```
<alias>
    <family>monospace</family>
    <prefer>
        <family>Meslo LG M DZ for Powerline</family>
        <family>DejaVu Sans Mono</family>
        <family>Inconsolata</family>
    </prefer>
</alias>
```

and it works as expected

Answer (score 0):

I used this snippet in the past with success,

```
<!--    Scaling a chosen font with Fontconfig.
        By poige, 2008.
     -->
    <match target="font">
        <test name="family">
            <string>Liberation Sans</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="pixelsize" mode="assign">
            <times><name>pixelsize</name>, <double>1.1</double></times>
        </edit>
    </match>
```

[Here is the source of this snippet](http://poige.livejournal.com/303641.html?nojs=1), but in Russian language.

Comment: This does not change the default monospace font, but rather changes the font size